# How to switch from Lubuntu to Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, lubuntu

I've just installed `xubuntu-desktop` on my trusty Lenovo X61 on top of Lubuntu 13.10. However, when the machine boots up it always logs straight into a Lubuntu session without asking. To resolve this I tried uninstalling lubuntu with `sudo apt-get remove lubuntu-desktop` but this turned out to be a bad idea as it booted to a black screen.

In tty1 I re-installed lubuntu and now I'm back to square 1. But I want Xubuntu!

I've heard taskel can be used to manage startup but wondered what the community would recommend. Many thanks.

Robin

Comment: The answer was about Ubuntu 12.10 and does not work for me - get various messages along the lines of "E: Unable to locate package ..." - Lubuntu booted as normal after

Comment: system settings --> login screen 
choose Xubuntu as default.

Comment: Hi Chester thanks for the hint and I think that could solve it. However, you need to be more specific/precise. Lubuntu 13.10 does not seem to have "system settings". Main Menu -> Preferences -> Desktop Session Settings is the closest I get but this contains no option to set Xubuntu as default. Think I'll just reinstall Xubuntu over the top of Lubuntu and be done with it.

Comment: I was able to switch from Ubuntu to Lubuntu here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/971121/how-do-i-switch-from-ubuntu-to-lubuntu-hundreds-of-package-not-found Basically you have to uninstall first, then install the new one, then reboot, then use `apt-get autoremove` to get rid of the old packages, then 'update', then reboot again, then `apt-get update`, then reboot again. Something like that. Use 'autoremove' or else your old desktop will override your new desktop.